# Resize/Compress image before uplaod in vue js, element ui upload component

Tags: file-upload, vuejs2, element-ui

I have an application where I want to pre-process image before upload in Vue js application. I'm using element UI for the front end.

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload#upload

Comment: You mean compress image size?

Comment: yes, I mean reducing images size/quality by percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code from @bosnaufal. This code can compress the size image.

You can install it via NPM

`npm install vue-image-compressor`

Import the module

`import imageCompressor from 'vue-image-compressor'`

Usage

`export default { components: { imageCompressor }, methods: { getFiles(obj){ console.log(obj); } } };`

for officially can see this link - https://github.com/BosNaufal/vue-image-compressor#vue-image-compressor

Comment: Is there any way, I want to use that same component but I want to pre-process before upload. However, for sake of solution, I used vue file pond component that is working fine too.

Comment: @MohsinAli What component you use for pre-processing?